# Is there an event in Lightswitch html tables to intercept selected row change

Tags: lightswitch-2013

I want to put a Delete button on my Screen whose state depends on if a row is selected in the Screen and some other conditions... basically I want to let the user be able to delete the current selected item, the problem here is that I can't find an appropriate event in the table to add custom logic when a new row becomes active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the delete button's _canExecute() method just put the following code:

```
myapp.MyScreen.DeleteButton_canExecute = function (screen) {
    return screen.Orders.selectedItem != null;
};
```

You can also control whether the button is visible when disabled by checking or unchecking the "Hidden if disabled" checkbox in the properties for the selected button.

Comment: solved my problem perfectly, however 1 question. if it does return null and the button is on each individual row, is there away to select the row that the button is currently on?